# Find maximal subsequence of array with indexes

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, subsequence

I would like to find the maximal subsequence `S(h,k)` in an array of integer. I already have the code (in Java) to find the maximum value  and it works fine, but how can I get the two indexes `h` and `k` from the following?

```
int []a = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    max_ending_here = Math.max(0, max_ending_here + a[i]);
    max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
}
System.out.println("The maximal sum of subsequence is = "+max_so_far)";
```

Comment: is this what you looking for? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Comment: No it's not. But I found on this site the correct solution, working also with all the numbers negative.  http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/o4cxS2

Answer (score 0):

You can get the subsequence itself by storing the last index at which you improved `max_so_far`, and "unraveling" the sequence from the back:

```
int []a = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0, index_max = 0;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    max_ending_here = Math.max(0, max_ending_here + a[i]);
    if (max_so_far < max_ending_here) {
        max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        index_max = i;
    }
}
System.out.print("The maximal sum of subsequence is = "+max_so_far);
int j = index_max;
while (j >= 0 && max_so_far > 0) {
    max_so_far -= a[j--];
}
System.out.println(", from = "+(j+1)+" to "+index_max+", inclusive");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/gcREl1)

**Note:** Unraveling from the back using a marker is a common theme in dynamic programming algorithms. In your simple case `index_max` plays the role of a special marker, from which you look backward for the index that runs `max_so_far` into zero.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to **Shreyas Sarvothama** and **dasblinkenligh**t for their answers. I found a good solution this code written by Utsav Chokshi on the geeksforgeeks.org website.

The solution is:

```
int []a = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
int max_so_far = a[0], max_ending_here = a[0];
int curStartIndex = 0;
int maxStartIndex = 0;
int maxEndIndex = 0;

for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
        max_ending_here = Math.max(a[i], max_ending_here + a[i]);
        if(max_ending_here > max_so_far){
             max_so_far = max_ending_here;
             maxStartIndex = curStartIndex;
             maxEndIndex = i;
        }
        if(max_ending_here < 0){
            curStartIndex = i+1;
        }
}
```